# Django doesn't recognize package six

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this error:

```
No module named six
```

But if go to python and try:

```
import six
```

It works.

This is my full traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://queromaiseducacao.com.br/

Django Version: 1.6.5
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'simulado',
 'south',
 'multichoice',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'social_auth')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  99.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  339.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  223.             return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  230.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  32.         result = func(*args)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  97.             mod = import_module(mod_name)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/quiz/simulado/views.py" in <module>
  17. from pagseguro import Payment
File "/home/filipefr2/lib/python2.7/pagseguro/__init__.py" in <module>
  2. from pagseguro.api.v2.payment import Payment as PaymentV2
File "/home/filipefr2/lib/python2.7/pagseguro/api/v2/payment.py" in <module>
  10. import dateutil.parser
File "/home/filipefr2/lib/python2.7/dateutil/parser.py" in <module>
  24. from six import text_type, binary_type, integer_types

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named six
```

Comment: You sure the library is available in your project or your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: What does `print six.__file__` print when you successfully import `six`? Note that your traceback uses `/home/filipefr2/lib/python2.7` as the Python library path, are you certain that when you run the Python interpreter that that is the same one you run Django with?

Comment: are you using virtualenv?

Comment: I managed the situation. I just tried unistalled six and reinstalled it